# header('Content-type: application/octet-stream') cause 0 byte files

Tags: php, download

I'm using database query in PHP to retrieve a binary file. But when I'm trying to force download it, the header('Content-type:  application/octet-stream') line cause 0 byte files. Without that line I can download the file with full content. It's a binary file that's for sure so I just can't understand why that line causes the problem.
The code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM stored_file WHERE file_name = '$q'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $file = $row['data'];
}


    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$q);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo $file;
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Comment out all headers; enable error reporting and run your script. Post any error messages.

Comment: I got no error messages.

Comment: Although it seems that filesize($file) returns nothing.

Comment: Does `$file` actually exist? Does PHP complain about "no such file" or "permission denied". Note: `$file = $row['data']` not `$row['file_name']`.

Comment: The $file exists. if I comment out the headers it echos it out, "ÖG¤Îů8F'ÖŐ×{ç qfw7´ź$ŘLéŐŚ)ÓťÎ=ÚťZ¸Ş..." appears in the browser. 
It also works if I put it in a condition like this:
if($file){
header...}
 but filesize still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`filesize()`](http://php.net/filesize) won't return a meaningful value.

You have binary data in `$file`, **not** an *actual filename* as required as first parameter. Hence you would get an error. (Enable error_reporting! Not seeing errors, and not having them are two different things.)

So what you want to use there is `strlen($file)`, not `filesize()`.

Btw, `application/octet-stream` or other fill-ins have no use for forcing downloads. It's the `Content-Disposition:` header which is most crucial to that effect. You're still allowed to send the correct MIME type.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Is it crucial to use the Content-Length header?
About the error reporting. I enabled it the php.ini and even in the code:
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 so I don't understand why I didn't get the error messages.

Comment: As last resort try `set_error_handler("var_dump");` atop the script. The Content-Length: header is widely considered secondary, it will usually work without. The payload meta data is only required if you also implement Range: headers etc. like a webserver would.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the query I guess that in `$row['data']` is the binary data stored. To set the correct Content-Length header you should use `mb_strlen($row['data']);`. If no multibyte support (the mb_ functions) is activated on your machine, use strlen(). But be aware, this may result in akward results because the binary data could actually contain the EOF byte sequence and return a too short length. With the mb_strlen function you are on the save side.